# Como implementar uma lista dentro de outra? (Estrutura de dados 1 em C)

Tags: c

Eu tenho uma estrutura estática que defini como variável global: `class_alimentacao Tipos_alimentacao[3];` E não consigo fazer com que a posição `Tipos_alimentacao[i]`, receba o endereço da lista de animais. Estou perdido, sugestões? Eu nem consigo acessar os métodos inserir, porque eu programo em c++ e fico confuso com C. (Professor pediu em C...)

Veja o código:

Tipos de classificação de seres vivos que alimentam.

```
    typedef struct{
        char nome[50];
        struct Lista *animais;
        //struct NO *animais;
    } class_alimentacao; //Herbívoro, Onívoros e Carnívoro.
void consultarDataBase(class_alimentacao p){ printf("Tipo: %s\n",p.nome); }
```

NO_lista.

```
typedef struct NO{
    int id;
    char name;
    struct NO *proximo;
} NO;

typedef struct{
    NO *inicio;
    void(*ptr_metodo);
}Lista;
```

Métodos:

```
void insert(Lista *LISTA,int ID,char NAME){
    NO *ptr= (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
    ptr->id= ID;
    ptr->name= NAME;

    ptr->proximo= LISTA->inicio;
    LISTA->inicio= ptr; }

void exibir(Lista *LISTA){
    NO *inicio= LISTA->inicio;
    if(inicio!=NULL){
        while(inicio!=NULL){
            printf("%d\t",inicio->id);
            printf("%c",inicio->name);
            inicio= inicio->proximo;
        }
    } else{
        printf("Nenhum animal cadastrado!");
    } }
```

Main:

```
int main(){
    Lista *list; list->inicio= NULL; int i= 0;
    for(i= 0;i<3;i++){
        scanf("%s",Tipos_alimentacao[i].nome); int op= 1;
        printf("(1) - Cadastrar nome animal.\n(2) - Sair.\n"); scanf("%d",&op);
        while(op>0 && op<2){
            list= &Tipos_alimentacao[i].animais;
            insert(list,10,'m');
            //insert(Tipos_alimentacao[i].animais,10,'m');
            if(op==2)break; 
        } }
```

Como eu faria? Vejo que eu consigo acessar as variáveis do NO,com este argumento: `Tipos_alimentacao[i].animais->`, mais logo não acessaria os métodos: insert exibir. Por isso criei um `void (*ptr_metodo)` na estrutura da lista.

E ao fazer`list= &Tipos_alimentacao[i].animais;`, dá erro de incompatibilidade. E mesmo que desce certo, já iria ocorrer outro problema, pois eu criei um objeto list, sendo que quero uma nova lista, toda vez que criar um Tipo_alimentacao. Ao fazer a consulta, eu estaria exibindo a mesmo conteúdo do objeto `Lista *list`. Me compreende? Por isso fiz assim: `list= &Tipos_alimentacao[i].animais;` e passando como parâmetro no inserir.

Comment: poste algo compilável

Answer (score 0):

Em C provavelmente não precisaria dos ponteiros para as funções dentro da lista num problema tão simples, mas poderia ter. Aqui seria sempre a mesma função. Não há especialização e então seria só uma *frescura* a mais. Vou deixar no exemplo.

Se escrever uma implementação genérica de `Lista` nos moldes de `list` em `C++` não terá dificuldade em ter uma lista de listas ou uma lista de listas de listas e tal. E seria bem útil já que escreveria uma vez só. Apenas use a mágica de `void*`, o *type erasure* de C ;)

### Um exemplo mais simples em C

Considere que uma lista não é de animais ou de listas ou de `int`. É de nós.

Seja um nó:

```
typedef struct st_NO
{
    Animal*       animal;
    struct st_NO* ant;
    struct st_NO* prox;
}   NO;  // um no da lista
```

Devia ser `void*` mas vamos ficar com isso menos genérico. E considere que ter ponteiros para os dois lados é muito mais simples e não o contrário: navegar numa lista que só tem ponteiros para um lado é um porre.

O animal:

```
typedef struct
{
    int         id;
    const char* name;

}   Animal;  // um animal
```

Note que é muito mais simples encapsular o animal e usar apenas o endereço. Assim pode mudar o animal sem mudar as assinaturas das funções.

E a `Lista`afinal

```
typedef struct st_Lista
{
    NO*    inicio;
    NO*    fim;
    size_t size;
    // provavelmente nao precisa disso
    int (*insert)(struct st_Lista*, Animal*);
    int (*show)(struct st_Lista*, const char*);
    struct st_Lista* (*create)();  // construtor
    struct st_Lista* (*delete)(struct st_Lista*);  // destructor

}   Lista;  // uma lista afinal
```

Não acho que precise dos ponteiros para os métodos aqui, mas essa seria uma maneira de escrever, provavelmente o mais simples. Note que DENTRO da lista está o tamanho o início e o fim, o que minha avó chamava de "mão na roda".

**Um mínimo de funções**

```
// insere um animal numa lista, o simples
int insert(Animal* a, Lista* l);


// mostra uma lista na tela, com uma mensagem
// opcional
int show(Lista*, const char*);


// cria e destroi uma lista
Lista* create_l();
Lista* delete_l(Lista*);
```

Bem no estilo RAII de `C++` ter a função que apaga a lista retornando um endereço de lista permite invalidar o ponteiro na mesma linha. E retornar apenas o ponteiro na hora de criar e nunca usar listas estáticas facilita o uso.

### o header `coisas.h`

```
#define HERBIVORO_ 0
#define ONIVORO_ 1
#define CARNIVORO_ 2
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int         id;
    const char* name;

}   Animal;  // um animal


typedef struct st_NO
{
    Animal*       animal;
    struct st_NO* ant;
    struct st_NO* prox;
}   NO;  // um no da lista


typedef struct st_Lista
{
    NO*    inicio;
    NO*    fim;
    size_t size;
    // provavelmente nao precisa disso
    int (*insert)(struct st_Lista*, Animal*);
    int (*show)(struct st_Lista*, const char*);
    struct st_Lista* (*create)();  // construtor
    struct st_Lista* (*delete)(struct st_Lista*);  // destructor

}   Lista;  // uma lista afinal

typedef struct
{
    size_t  size;
    Lista** an;

}   Animais;  // um vetor de listas

// insere um animal numa lista, o simples
int insert(Animal* a, Lista* l);


// mostra uma lista na tela, com uma mensagem
// opcional
int show(Lista*, const char*);


// cria e destroi uma lista
Lista* create_l();
Lista* delete_l(Lista*);
```

### Uma implementação vazia `coisas.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "v1.h"

int insert(Animal* a, Lista* l) { return 0; }
int show(Lista* l, const char* msg) { return 0; }
Lista* create_l() { return NULL; }
Lista* delete_l(Lista* l) { return NULL; }
```

#### `main.c` para um teste

Apenas como exemplo de como acessar as coisas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "v1.h"

int main(void)
{
    Animal tigre    = {0, "tigre"};
    Animal coelho   = {1, "coelho"};
    Animal cascavel = {2, "cascavel"};

    Lista* l_herb = create_l();
    Lista* l_carn = create_l();
    Lista* l_oniv = create_l();

    insert(&tigre, l_carn);
    insert(&coelho, l_herb);
    insert(&cascavel, l_oniv);

    show(l_carn, "carnivoros ate aqui");
    show(l_herb, "herbivoros ate aqui");
    show(l_oniv, "onivoros ate aqui");

    Animais animais = {.size = 0, .an = NULL};

    animais.an = (Lista**)malloc(3 * sizeof(Lista*));
    animais.an[HERBIVORO_] = l_herb;
    ++animais.size;
    animais.an[CARNIVORO_] = l_carn;
    ++animais.size;
    animais.an[ONIVORO_] = l_oniv;
    ++animais.size;

    // apaga as listas
    l_herb = delete_l(l_herb);
    l_carn = delete_l(l_carn);
    l_oniv = delete_l(l_oniv);

    // esvazia a lista de animais
    free(animais.an);
    animais.an   = NULL;
    animais.size = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

HIH